# Is it possible to bring window to front without taking focus?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstextfield, nswindowcontroller

I am working on an application for my personal usage that will remind me of stuff at regular intervals and/or will require text entry. Hence this popup window has an NSTextField.

If the window pop's up when I am in the middle of typing, my typing transfers to the popup window which is very annoying! Is there any way to stop this, currently I am using:

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
[hudWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

I have also tried:

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
[hudWindow orderFrontRegardless];
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You could try using Growl.

Comment: The window I am trying to show needs to allow text entry. But yes, I'm also using growl as growl is cool.

Comment: You could bring your window forward if you click on the Growl notification.

Comment: Have you tried `-orderFront:` or `-orderFrontRegardless:` without `-activateIgnoringOtherApps:`?

Comment: Can this be used to set focus to a desktop and then window of another Process ID's most recent window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[hudWindow orderFront: nil];
```

Moves the window to the front of its level in the screen list, without changing either the key window or the main window.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using setLevel:? Setting it to one of the higher levels should do the trick.

like

> [hudWindow
>   setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel];